# How to insert / Delete record in repository pattern unit of work entity framework with combined primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

I have a following table with only two column with combined primary key

**Table Name :** ProductByUser

**Column  1 :** ProductId *(FK Ref. to Product Table)*

**Column 2 :** *UserId (FK Ref. to User Table)*

***Additional Information:*** In edmx also I am not able to view this table but it show direct relationship between Product & User Table.

I am not able to make out how to delete or Insert record into this table. As I am not directly able to create an object of this table. So kindly guide me on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got the way out , Hope this will help some one in future,

```
 void Insert(Product product, int intUserId)
  {
     _unitofWork.Db.Entry(product).Collection(i => i.Users).Load();

      UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository(_unitofWork);

     product.Users.Add(userRepo.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(U => U.UserID == intUserId));

  }
```

For deleting

```
 product.Users.Remove(userRepo.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(U => U.UserID == intUserId));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ProductByUser // Many to many table implemented as entity
{
    public int ProductId  { get; set; }
    public int UserId  { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
   modelBuilder.Entity<ProductByUser>()
       .HasKey(c => new { c.ProductId , c.UserId });

   modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
       .HasMany(c => c.ProductUsers)
       .WithRequired()
       .HasForeignKey(c => c.ProductId);

   modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
       .HasMany(c => c.ProductUsers)
       .WithRequired()
       .HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks Univ for Answering , I have try to do so, but I am getting following error.Additional information: The entity type ProductByUser is not part of the model for the current context.

Comment: Did you map each entity to a table? For example for ProductByUser you need:   modelBuilder.Entity<ProductByUser >().ToTable("ProductByUser ");

Comment: Do you mind sharing the entity configuration code that you have for these three entities?

Comment: Thanks but found the way out , :) , Thanks a lot